# "This chick's playing with Confederate money." (Seinfeld)

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "This chick's playing with Confederate money."

It is from *Seinfeld*. *Elaine* said that when was trying to convince *Jerry* that some girl had fake breasts. How to decipher it?

There is probably an interplay between the words 'silicone' and 'silicon'. Maybe the Confederate States of America had something significant in the Silicon Valley.

Comment: Could she have said "counterfeit", maybe? Counterfeit meaning fake, hence the fake breasts?

Comment: @Roger: Not the case.

Comment: Confederate States abandoned 1865. California became a state in 1850

Comment: California sided with the North in the Civil War. But in any case, as Michael Martinez explains in his answer, this has nothing to do with the real answer to the question. BTW nobody talked about "Silicon Valley" until well after the Civil War. The name comes from the silicon used to make computer chips, and silicon-based computer chips were not invented until about 100 years after the Civil War.

Comment: Isn't anyone who has read this question enough of a _Seinfeld_ fan to know that Elaine is prone to mispronunciations and malapropisms?  You're all overanalyzing this.  She meant "counterfeit."  The woman she's talking about is bringing something fake to the "dating game" just like a gambler playing poker with counterfeit money.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Has nothing to do with silicon or Silicon Valley. It refers to the fact that Confederate money became worthless after the Civil War. She is saying: just as Confederate money is not "real" money, so silicone breasts are not real breasts.

Comment: Who could know better than someone who actually lives in the Silicon Valley :)

Comment: Silicon Valley is named thus because of the manufacture of computer chips in the 1970s. It has nothing to do with plastic surgery.

Comment: I know. I thought there is a very subtle interplay between the words 'silicon' and 'silicone', which kind of connect Silicon Valley with silicone breasts :)

Answer (score 4):

Towards the end of the American Civil War, the [Confederate States' dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederate_States_of_America_dollar) became nearly worthless due to massive inflation (similar to the phrase "not worth [a Continental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_American_currency#Continental_currency)", stemming from the Revolutionary War, or the more recent [hyperinflation in Zimbabwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperinflation_in_Zimbabwe)).

A simple explanation (thanks [Alicja Z](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20285/this-chicks-playing-with-confederate-money-seinfeld#comment37624_20286)) is that it's this **inflation** that she was referring to.

Another possibility: Being so worthless, you could almost say that the money had become **fake**. She could also be implying that the fakes are worthless, or not as valuable, as the real thing. If Roger's comment is correct and she said "counterfeit", this meaning of "fake" becomes more directly true.

Silicon Valley wasn't part of the Confederate States: Texas is [as far west](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederate_States_of_America) as the states of the nation had gone by that time. So it's very unlikely that this is the intended meaning.

Comment: +1 But "not worth a Continental" goes back to the Revolutionary era, and referred to the dollar issued by the Continental Congress.

Comment: @StoneyB haha, apparently my brain stops after the third letter. I'll fix that...

Comment: Hmm... What if the keyword here isn't _fake_ but rather _inflation_?

Comment: @AlicjaZ Ooh, very good point. I've added that as my first suggestion.

Comment: Confederate States abandoned 1865. California became a state in 1850

Comment: I think the meaning is just "fake", since following the end of the American Civil War the money would have been worthless (inflation or no).

Comment: If you read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederate_States_dollar), the dollar was only ever a promise to pay the holder money six months (or later 2 years) after the signing of a peace treaty establishing the Confederacy's survival as an independent nation. In fact, its value dropped as the likelihood of a Southern victory dwindled, until after the war, with no Confederate government to redeem the notes, they were worthless. (Although there were some people who hoarded them, believing some day they would be redeemed or the south would rise again.)

Answer (score -2):

### Elaine misspoke.

The intended term must have been "**counterfeit** money".

Although actress Julia Louis-Dreyfus did say "confederate money" in the actual episode, it's highly unlikely that the original script used that term.  She probably delivered the line incorrectly.

Instead, the proper term would be "counterfeit money".  "Counterfeit" describes a fake and fraudulent imitation of something else, something with real value, such as currency or an artwork.  In context, "counterfeit" makes perfect sense in the scene, and would be a humorous way to describe fake breasts.

On the other hand,  "confederate" doesn't make much sense at all in this context.  Perhaps it's possible to devise a convoluted justification for writing the word "confederate" into this scene (as other answers here have attempted), but such explanations are really not very plausible.

So, "counterfeit" is the most appropriate word in the English language for the given context and "confederate" is similar-sounding but nonsensical in context. Therefore, the simple explanation is that the actress misremembered her line and substituted a similar-sounding word for the correct one.  Another possibility is that the script itself contains an error, due to a flawed transcription or other mistake.  Both explanations make more sense than "confederate money".

Comment: It is very likely that *confederate* was in the script.  It is a common idiom for counterfeit and would have been intended as humourous.  It is not nonsensical at all to use it.

Comment: I have never heard of *confederate* being used in this way. Nonetheless, I did perform a few Google searches to see if there were any such uses, or any Slang dictionaries that listed a relationship between the two words. I could find none. Do you happen to have a reference?

Comment: If not, I’ll have to take your word for it being common… somewhere, even if it’s rarely heard here in the mid-Atlantic region of the US. May I ask which region of the Anglosphere you’ve heard *confederate money* used in place of *counterfeit money*? Is it really used in your native England, so far from the original Confederacy?

Comment: It would be interesting to learn, for instance, that the term IS used in the US, but only *outside* regions which were covered by the actual Confederacy. That would make some degree of sense. After all, in these states, it wasn’t “fake money” at all: it was real, at least for a few years.

Comment: Either way, ANY reference — a dictionary, thesaurus, or an example usage in literature — would be very interesting to see. Sorry I’ve failed to dig up such a reference so far. I did try.

Comment: The existence of [Confederate dollars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederate_States_dollar) is discussed in other answers: such currency was worthless after the fall of the Confederacy, and tied to the Confederacy, an institution which Jerry as a New York Jew would regard with utter contempt. The fact that some currency was hoarded by (pro-slavery) eccentrics in the ["futile hope"](https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/object-of-intrigue-confederate-currency) of it being redeemed adds to the status of Confederate dollars as worthless notes no different to Monopoly money.

Comment: Thank you, @StuartF, for your response, and for the links.  I am aware of the currency's existence, and I'm aware that it would not be legal tender in New York in the 1990s.  I should acknowledge that interpretation of Elaine's remark as being a step above "nonsensical".

Comment: Still, I was hoping for **any reference al all** to corroborate the assertion by an earlier commenter that the term _confederate_ can be used as a synonym for _counterfeit_ according to "common idiom".